# How to preview selected pictures with jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can I get src of my selected pictures from a multiple file input.

This is my actual code, it uses lorempicsum for design purpose:

```
$('#multiple-files').on('change', function() {
    console.log(this.files); // I get all my files properly.

    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        var image_path = 'http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/460/460/' + (i+1);
        $('#files').append('<img src="'+ image_path +'" class="img-rounded img-responsive">')
    }
});
```

And this is my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/upload" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="upload-image" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="browse" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span>  Select pictures
    </div>

    <input multiple="multiple" id="multiple-files" accept="image/*" name="file[]" type="file">

    <div id="files">

    </div>

    <div style="display: none;" class="row" id="form-buttons">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block" id="reset" value="Reset" type="reset">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" value="Upload" type="submit">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/8Dy4ZAp.png

Comment: please provide HTML also

Comment: You can't, a fake pathname is used so you can't include the image directly, you have to use the fileReader, convert to base64, and then use that.

Comment: You cant set image src To Image in Computer. You do one thing.As soon the image is selected ,upload it to server via AJAX ,and then access via your Serverside language like PHP

Comment: I never use the fileReader or made conversion into base64 ... Someone to help me? I don't want to upload first. Only check the selected pictures in an elegant way.

Comment: You want to show IMAGE preview as soon as file uploads by client?

Comment: Yes a preview of all selected pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate and convert to base64, then insert the image tags

```
$('#multiple-files').on('change', function (e) {
    $.each(e.target.files, function(_, file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (ev) {
            var img = $('<img />', {src : ev.target.result});
            $('#files').append(img);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tYbQj/)

Answer (score 0):

Use file reader

You can get beautiful answer here [Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Use following code

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});</script>
</body>
```

Try the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/

Comment: How to combine this script with mine? I need to append the img element with its correct DataURL for each file in files[].

Comment: You mean You want to append multiple images ?

Comment: Yes for each picture in files[], I need to append an img element inside my #files div.

Comment: Thanks! I added a screenshot (with comments) at the end of my question.